# C# .net Make listview items clickable

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to click on items in the listview. Is there a way to do this? I would like to **click on each one individually** (and from that action, write to hardware, change the on/off indication (bold font), and update the hex value for that register.

I've found how to click on the columns via msdn, but I cannot figure out how to click on the items. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.oncolumnclick

I don't have much experience, but it seems like I should be able to interface from Control.Onclick somehow: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onclick(v=vs.110).aspx

[image: listview items that I want clickable]

Comment: Do you mean _[FullRowSelect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.fullrowselect(v=vs.110).aspx)_ ?

Comment: Not quite, I want to click on each one individually, if that is possible with a listview.

Comment: The LV doesnt have an Item- or SubItem Click event exposed, only a DoubleClick with generic args.  It is not hard to subclass it and add a `SubItemClick` event by overrides `OnMouseUp` though

Comment: @Plutonix Are there better ways of getting clickable read-only cells of text?

Comment: not that I can think of since the lack of the events mentioned prevents a decent starting point.  Its kind of a brain dead control in some ways, which is why it is subclassed and rewritten so often.

Comment: Can you offer any references for how this is done? I'm something of a brain dead programmer. I understand what you are saying, and it sounds like it will work, but I am unclear on how to carry out the details. I'm pretty new to .NET and OO techniques, so any references would be great.

--- 

So to summarize, I need to subclass the doubleclick event and put an `OnMouseUP` event in it?

Comment: `new System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(null, "REV_ID")` --- This is how I create the list view subitems (the cells). -- I'm going through the example here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.listviewsubitem(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Could you use a DataGridView control instead? It has a CellClick event.

Comment: Subclassing is done on a control, not an event.  You'd be creating a whole new LV control which adds a SubItemClick.  The DGV is an actual grid which is much more powerful and already exposes what you want.  I'd use that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code.

Handle the `ListView_MouseUp` event and write down the following code.

```
private void listView1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (listView1.View != View.Details)
        return; 
    int rowIndex = getRowIndex(e.Location);
    if (rowIndex == -1)
        return ;
    int columnIndex = getColumnIndex(e.Location);
    if (columnIndex > -1)
        OnCellClick(rowIndex, columnIndex);
}
```

Now, create the method to get the Column Index according to mouse position. This method will find the column index according to mouse position.

```
private int getColumnIndex(Point p)
{
    Rectangle r = Rectangle.Empty;
    r = Rectangle.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        r = new Rectangle(r.X + r.Width, 0, listView1.Columns[i].Width, listView1.Height);
        if (r.Contains(p))            
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Create another method to get the Row Index according to mouse position. This method will find the row index according to mouse position and it will set the `FocusedItem` property of ListView. So, you can get the focus on the clicked item.

```
private int getRowIndex(Point p)
{
    Rectangle r = Rectangle.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        Rectangle r1 = listView1.GetItemRect(i);
        r = new Rectangle(0, r1.Top, listView1.Width, r1.Height);
        if (r.Contains(p))
        {
            listView1.FocusedItem = listView1.Items[i];
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

This is the method that you need to handle. Your code to get the value from ListView cell will be written in this method.

```
private void OnCellClick(int RowIndex, int ColumnIndex)
{

    MessageBox.Show("Column : " + ColumnIndex.ToString() + ", Row: " + RowIndex.ToString());
}
```

*I know there is no need to create method to get the `RowIndex`. We can get the Item directly from location by using `GetItemAt(x,y)` method. But, this method only works when you have set the `FullRowSelect` to `true` otherwise you will get `null` when the mouse position is on subitem.*